# CSS property with no value

Tags: css

I'm designing a GUI for users to create web buttons. I'm wondering if it's ok to not enter a value for a CSS property?

I've looked into inserting a property's default value if a user doesn't select one. But I run into a problem with properties that have no default value like "color". I found a reference for all CSS properties at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_Reference

I've tested it in the most recent versions of all 5 major browsers and it seams to work fine; but I'm not sure if that will always hold true in the future. I have considered programmically, with PHP, removing the entire property if a user doesn't choose a value for it. But I want to know what your thoughts are on using CSS properties without specifying a value before doing that?

CSS:

```css
.btn {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-style:;
    border-width:2px;
    color:;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is my solution:

I simply remove any CSS properties that are not defined by the user with PHP.

```
$css = preg_replace('/[\n\r].+:;/i', '', $css);
```

Comment: You could use "auto" or "inherit".

Comment: I think it will be fine, it wont validate, but it wont mess anything up either. Browsers are prepared for people to misspell stuff, so they just wont pay attention to empty rules.

Comment: If a user doesn't specify a value can you not just not include that css rule?

Comment: @scrappedcola, using `inherit` is very different from not setting a property, and so is `auto`, which is an allowed value for some properties only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While properties do have default values in some cases(*), it usually doesn't work that way. What the specs do is provide *initial* values, which are usually mentioned in the specs. `color` is one of the few exceptions in that the default value is the value of the user preference (in Firefox, Edit -> Preferences -> Content -> Colors -> Text). Most others do have well-defined initial values, e.g. for `border-style` it's `none`.

This is the official W3C documentation, which is the standard:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/

To be absolutely clear, properties must have a value according to the rules. A property without a value is an error and will be ignored.

(*) Example: in shorthands like `border:green`, you don't have to specify `border-style` and `border-width` and those are then set to their default (initial) values.

Comment: If the downvoter can explain what's wrong with my answer, I can improve it, so it won't have the negative points you feel it now has, and you can retract your downvote. Win-win!

Comment: Properties have initial values; this is not the same as default values. The whole issue is not relevant to the question. The behavior is not undefined.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You're absolutely right. Is it better like this?

Comment: To clarify: an "initial value" is the value that should be used with a property if it is not specified and/or cannot be computed to a usable value. This initial value is determined by the spec. A "default value", on the other hand, is simply the value that is specified by a default user agent stylesheet. The only difference between UA style properties and author style properties is the location in which they're declared.

Comment: @BoltClock But in some cases, like in my example, the default values of the properties _are_ governed by the specs. The user cannot add anything to a stylesheet that says the border-width should become (e.g.) `10px`, if there's `border:green;` in the CSS. The border-width _will_ become `medium`. (Unless of course, you hack your browser's data files, but I cannot recommend that.)

Answer (score 9):

A declaration without value, such as `color:;`, violates CSS syntax, so it’s not OK by the book. On the other hand, the CSS 2.1 specification defines mandatory [error processing principles](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors), which say that such a rule shall be ignored by the user agent (note that the spec explicitly mentions a missing property value as an example of “malformed declaration”).

This means that the value of the property will be determined by the user agent as if this part of your style sheet did not exist. Thus, the value will be defined by other style sheets that might be applied (including browser default style sheets, which define browser defaults for properties) or, in the absence of relevant settings in other style sheets, by the initial value of the property as designated in CSS specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *initial* property value which will make the property use it's initial value, or the browsers default value. I'm not sure about the support for it but I'm pretty sure I've been using it for a long time now and it's always worked for me in at least IE8+.

```
color: initial;
```

Comment: not supported by IE till the time of writing, I don't use it